# Upload explorer error

Tags: search, uploads

I am trying to upload some files from my phone to a few sites.
Unfortunately, the file explorer doesn't show the files in any of the following lists... Recent, downloads, etc

The files are in the download folder but are not being displayed.

How do you refresh the file explorer so that the files are shown, and can be uploaded??